# pause live-data or reactivity for cursor

Tags: meteor

In my application the user gets a list of documents which have arrived for her and can do things with each document.

The documents are submitted in batches and the list grows when this happens. This is all good and well and it is the expected behaviour but it would be nice to have a button ´suspend live data´ which would ignore new documents and the list would remain as it is until the button is pressed again and live data is activated again.

either the reactivity or the live-data need to be suspended. But only for one cursor.

any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the `reactivity` option

e.g

```
Template.hello.data = function() {
    var state = Session.get("reactive") || false;
    return MyCollection.find({},{reactive:state});
}
```

So you could set `Session.set("reactive",<true or false>)` to change whether to make the cursor reactive or not.